# xsl implementation for an xml file

Tags: xslt

need to  convert  an xml file having a tag(dynamicVariable) that has an attribute(name).This xml file has to be converted using xsl into the same xml file such that the tag (dynamicVariable) should have the same structure along with it and its the tag-content  also should be the value of the attribute.

need to convert the below xml file

```
   <Content>
     <alertHeader>
         <text xmlns="http://abc.com" xmlns:w="http://def.com"> Claim  
           <dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference" />: More Information Needed
         </text>
         <contactUs>false</contactUs>
     </alertHeader>


     <body>
         <text> ATM/Debit Card Claim: 
         <strong><dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference" /></strong>
         </text>
     </body>

         </Content>
```

into the same format but the  tag having 'name' attribute should appear in the output xml file as this format

```
      <dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference" />Claim_Reference</dynamicVariable>
```

Can anyone provide the necessary xsl file in converting the same. Hope that its done using

```
    <xsl:copy></xsl:copy>  or <xsl:copy-of /> tags .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As simple as this**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
     <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

     <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
         <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
         </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="*[name() = 'dynamicVariable']">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
      </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Content>
    <alertHeader>
        <text xmlns="http://abc.com" xmlns:w="http://def.com"> Claim              
            <dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference" />: More Information Needed          
        </text>
        <contactUs>false</contactUs>
    </alertHeader>
    <body>
        <text> ATM/Debit Card Claim:           
            <strong>
                <dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference" />
            </strong>
        </text>
    </body>
</Content>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<Content>
   <alertHeader>
      <text xmlns="http://abc.com" xmlns:w="http://def.com"> Claim
            <dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference">Claim_Reference</dynamicVariable>: More Information Needed
        </text>
      <contactUs>false</contactUs>
   </alertHeader>
   <body>
      <text> ATM/Debit Card Claim:
            <strong>
            <dynamicVariable name="Claim_Reference">Claim_Reference</dynamicVariable>
         </strong>
      </text>
   </body>
</Content>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The **[identity rule](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)** copies every node "as-is".
2. A single template overrides the identity template. It matches any that has athe name "`dynamicVariable`" regardless of namespace, and that is a child of `strong` (thus specifying more context helps us process only this occurence of `dynamicVariable` but leave the preceding one "as-is").
3. The overriding tempalte shallo-copies the current node, then copies its attributes, then finally creates a text-node child whose contents is the string value of the `name` attribute of the current (matched) element.

Comment: thankyou. But i want the same thing to be done to every dynamic variable tag(no matter where they are in the document, and are having different attribute values to 'name' attribute ). Can you post the related code to it.

Comment: the code that you have posted is not working for the first 'dynamicVariable'tag too .

Comment: @Jeevan: So, you want this also to be done to the `dynamicVariable` under `alertHeader` ? Please, confirm. If so, should the existing text-node child be replaced, or should it also stay?

Comment: @Jeevan: I updated my answer -- the transformation now does the required processing on every `dynamicVariable` element.

Comment: @Jeevan: I am glad that "the code is fine". If so, could you, please, *accept* the answer (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer) ?

Comment: @Dimitri : When i try executing your xslt code im getting the namespaces associated with the source xml file in the transformed xml .

Comment: suppose if you consider xmlns:e="http://abc.com" xmlns:w="http://def.com" xmlns:g="http://abe.com" are the namespaces associated with the root element of source xml file when we do <copy-of> for the <dynamicVariable> tag then the transformed output xml file has <dynamicVariable xmlns:e="http://abc.com" xmlns:w="http://def.com" xmlns:g="http://abe.com" > in it.I try including result-exclude-prefixes in the <xsl:stylesheet> tag for these namespaces but even though i couldn't eleminate these namespaces from the output. Please give a solution for this.

Comment: @Jeevan: Do you mean that the result isn't the one I am providing in the answer, or that the result I am providing in the answer isn't the one you wanted?

Comment: @Jeevan: My guess is that you are applying the transformation on a different XML document. If so, that means the new XML document is so *significantly* different than the one provided in your question, that I would recommend asking a *new* question and providing in it the new XML document.

Comment: @Jeevan: When an element is copied -- either using `<xsl:copy>` or `<xsl:copy-of>`, all of the namespace nodes it has are also copied with it -- this is what you see. The only way to get rid of such namespace nodes is not to use such copying instructions, but to re-create the element using `<xsl:element>`

Comment: I'm satisfied with the solution that you have provided. But i have one more issue which i'm facing when i apply your solution to it,which i would like to bring into your notice for the same xml file with some modifications.

Comment: @Jeevan: Please, ask a new question -- the comments formatting isn't suitable. Also, there are a number of already answered questions how to get rid of namespace nodes -- I'll still be delighted to answer your new question.

Comment: Hey thanks man. The Hint that you gave to re-create the element really worked.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:t="http://abc.com">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dynamicVariable[@name]|t:dynamicVariable[@name]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: it fulfills your criteria, and the output is as you posted it

Comment: see Dimitre's answer for a complete xsl stylesheet, he uses the same template body as me.